# Using properties file for user credentials with java configuration in Spring security

Tags: spring-security

In XML configuration it's possible to refer to a property file defining user credentials. For example:

```
<security:user-service id="userDetailsService" properties="classpath:users.properties"/>
```

However in java configuration there is no default alternative available (that I'm aware of) but writing your own implementation like:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:users.properties");
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(properties);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if it would make a nice addition to have this provided by the spring security framework out of the box. Something like :

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication("classpath:user.properties")
    ...
```

or

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUserCredentialsFile("classpath:user.properties")
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if adding this improvement to Spring Security makes sense. As you had outlined, the equivalent Java Configuration would be:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
    Properties users = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("users.properties");
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
}
```

This looks pretty straight forward for the user. What do you think?

Comment: That's indeed the solution that I also implemented myself (without the use of the PropertiesLoaderUtils, which makes it even more neat). I guess it's not that much of an added value to have it in the API when it's only 2 lines of extra configuration. Thx for the feedback!